# What would the population and financial requirements be to create a self-sustaining country based on UBI that could be apart of the global economy

Tags: society, technological-development, civilization, population, colonies

If a mega rich individual wanted to test the validity of UBI (Universal Basic Income) in the most efficient way possible and how it integrates into a global modern economy, what would the population and startup requirements be? What would the maintaining requirements be?

Assuming a temperate climate location with a moderate amount of any natural resources and the cost to acquire the land would be free. The location would be the most economically efficient location to import and export.

The citizens of this country would be volunteers to participate in this coming from anywhere in the world, but obviously we want to start with the minimum amount viable and only accept people for the roles needed to have a society that's self sustaining enough but can produce enough export value (both goods and internet related fields) to trade on a global scale. The foundation for this country, such as road infrastructure, businesses, housing and farms would have to be mainly established already. The goal would be to immediately provide a UBI for each citizen of this country, but also have businesses able to offer additional payment to be able to access specialized goods from a global economy. this country would be heavily oriented towards public transportation. If people wanted personal vehicles they would have to import it themselves from other countries.

What would the population count need to be to mostly self sustain the country. Obviously things like computer chips, robotics, etc. would have to be brought in from imports and thus this country would need to have a currency that could participate in global exchange.

What would the UBI have to be, to be able to participate in a global economy to sustain a modern basic life inside this country.

If the mega rich individual wanted to earn his money back (not profit) in the form of taxes, what would that look like and how long would it take without impeding the self-sustenance or quality of life of this country.

**To summarize:**

- What would the population requirement be to self-sustain modern european living (public transportation, mainly apartments) and the roles of the population
- How much will it cost to build this country and how? How long? Hiring the most cost efficient labor in the world and acquiring the most cost efficient modern materials in the world to build this country to be ready to be inhabited.
- How will this country participate in global trade to obtain the specialized goods they need they could not provide for themselves due to economy of scale
- What would the UBI system need to provide each month to cover basic needs in this country but offering enough opportunity to take take extra income earned to be able to be worth something in the global economy
- If the mega rich individual wanted to earn his money back in the form of taxes, since he did establish all infrastructure of the country, what would that look like and how long would it take without impeding the self-sustenance or quality of life of this country.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! Unfortunately, we have a strict one-question-per-post policy, and you have five.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding UBI (or I might misunderstand how you use the term).

A society **generates** and **consumes** goods and services. UBI is one possible tool to help distribute the generated goods and services for consumption, just like taxes in general, fiscal policy, pension schemes, etc. Making UBI work is more a question of the ethics in society, the willingness of "overtly productive" members to share wealth with "less overtly productive" members.

Imagine an island with ten people which is, for the sake of argument, sovereign.

- One citizen is a computer programmer who works remotely for foreign customers, earning 10 coins.
- Another citizen is a farmer, producing food for sale on other islands worth 10 coins after expenses (it simplifies the example if all food which is eaten gets imported).
- Another citizen is a mason who earns 10 coins on other islands (there are enough houses on the example islands already).
- Another citizen is a cook who produces tasty meals from imported food, earning 2 coins after expenses from customers only on the island.
- Another citizen is a nurse who looks after two elderly citizens, earning 2 coins.
- Another citizen does most of the care work for a child.
- Another citizen does nothing much, but his songs are really popular on youtube. He doesn't manage to turn that fame into cash.

They could run a "pure" capitalist system. The computer programmer, the farmer and the mason pay the cook to cook, the childcarer is presumably married to one of the working people, the elderly have money saved to pay the nurse, the singer gets nothing much unless he finds an advertising contract.

There could be a state collecting taxes, mostly from the working people. The programmer, the farmer, and the mason are easily taxed. The cook would sell the food, again making it possible to tax him. The nurse would have an income to tax. Presumably the childcarer, the child, the pensioners and the singer have no income and pay no taxes, but they **might** get some sort of welfare or social security payments out of the budget. Likely the pensioners get something if their savings are insufficient, the childcarer gets nothing with the assumption that the spouse pays, and the singer gets nothing unless he shows that he tried to find a "real" job.

## Or the state could collect more taxes and give everyone the UBI.

Say the tax rate is 50% or thereabouts and the UBI is 1 coin. The programmer, the farmer, and the mason all pay 5 coins and get 1 coin back (effectively paying 4 coins), the cook and the nurse pay 1 coin and get the same back (effectively paying nothing) and the others get 1 coin.

The goods and services generated by the island are **completely unchanged**. They have a net 30 coins to spend on imports, they have three people who are working "high status" jobs, three people in "low status" jobs, and four not working much for various reasons. All which differs is how the wealth is distributed.

## The Challenges:

- Set UBI high enough that it is sufficient for basic living (the singer in the example), yet low enough to encourage many people to work above and beyond UBI. In the example, the nurse might say "if I stop working, I'll have half the money for none of the hassle."
- Set UBI low enough that those who do extra work are not overwhelmed by taxes.
- Make the society large enough to "average out" exceptional years. If the mason and the farmer decide to go on a sabbatical and form a band with the singer, the sample little island is in trouble. Even at 100% tax rate the programmer couldn't pay for everything.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The question assumes that UBI is something very special, whereas in reality it is just a mechanism to make uniform taxation work like variable-rate progressive taxation + social security while simplifying the procedures considerably. The only possible disadvantage is that it would put a lot of paper pushers out of work.

Comment: @AlexP, another difference/possible disadvantage is that people are not "encouraged" to seek work while they are on the dole. The reduced overhead may or may not outweigh this.

Comment: Many European countries already sustain people who are out of work indefinitely. It doesn't stop them from runnig very sucessful economies. That's why I said "+ social security" (which in Europe is entirely different from American uppercase Social uppercase Security).

Comment: @AlexP, social security in many EU countries is indefinite but often tied to attempts to help the recipient find work -- attempts which may or may not be effective but certainly put pressure on the recipient.

Comment: While this is currently the most detailed answer, the one weakness I find is there is no allowance for changes in behaviour due to taxation or receipt of UBI. High income earners might be expected to respond negatively to high taxation, and marginal cases may choose to go either way depending on incentives. Many similar experiments (like leveling class marks) show high "earners" reacting negatively and overall "productivity" falls.

Comment: @Thucydides, I tried to do that with the three bullet points at the end.The second bullet point are people overwhelmed by taxes, the first bullet point are people who find UBI more comfortable than work. I could change an example to introduce someone who earns even closer to UBI, but the cook and the nurse are close.

Answer (score 1):

## What does the country produce?

This is the key question you need to answer. Alaska has a [limited form of UBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Permanent_Fund) that comes from its rich oil supplies. You mention that your country has "a moderate amount of any natural resources." Are you OK with stripmining the entire country for maximum profit? In that case, you could have a relatively small population of miners and support personnel all living off of UBI paid for by taxes collected on the natural resource exports.

Regarding infrastructure costs, here are estimates of the costs of building [roads in India](https://www.quora.com/In-general-what-is-the-cost-of-road-construction-per-kilometer-in-India) and [trains in China](http://www.globalconstructionreview.com/sectors/why-china-can-build-high-speed-rail34socheaply7365/). However, it is common for mining companies to build their own infrastructure. Let's look at a real world example.

Here's [an investor presentation](https://www.northerndynastyminerals.com/site/assets/files/4806/ndm_corporate_april8_2020-web.pdf) from Northern Dynasty Minerals. Key numbers for your consideration:

- Employment: 850 direct hires and 1,250 other jobs created
- Annual costs: 400 million USD
- Annual taxes: 49 million to 66 million USD

Use those as a sanity check rather than something you can directly copy. If you have to bring every local worker (doctors, clergy, administrators, public transit operators, etc.) then your employment numbers will have to be higher. Barick's latest [quarterly earnings report](https://barrick.q4cdn.com/788666289/files/quarterly-report/2020/Barrick-Q1-2020-Report.pdf) says that mining company spent 370 million USD in "Minesite sustaining capital expenditures" in only three months, so a larger operation would obviously cost you even more.

TLDR: if your megarich donor has a billion dollars or so to spare every year, she could probably get her money back in a couple of years by extracting and exporting natural resources.

Comment: The problem with making your UBI based on raw resource production is, what happens when it runs out?  What happens when the world's market moves away from that resource?  Alaska is a great example actually.  Nothing good will happen to their UBI when all that oil has been pumped, or when the world finally moves to green energy.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Cuba is large enough, since Cuba DOES have a UBI. That would be 11 million people. That sets the upper limit to minimum population necessary.

But Cuba makes this a political question, not an economic one. Cuba would be thriving if it were not for American sanctions, imposed for political reasons.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuba

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/68984)

Comment: @ From Review – ProjectApex  'What would the population count need to be to mostly self sustain the country.' Cuba self-sustains with a UBI with a population count of 11 million.'How will this country participate in global trade to obtain the specialized goods they need they could not provide for themselves due to economy of scale'. The definition of 'self-sustaining' varies if the country is subject to sanctions. The question answer therefore depends on the response of other countries and on political considerations. Why is that not an answer?

Comment: although you do give a population number, half of your question (minus link) is focused on saying Cuba has issues due to the USA. Don't forget they never recovered after they lost the USSR's economic support, and that their condition is that of a country essentially stopped in time for most of the population. You should state these in your answer as well, even if the link covers some of the information. Rather than not an answer, I'd better say it can be a much better answer if you give us more information of *how* Cuba can and would thrive without the sanctions.

Comment: @ProjectApex  It is your bias that says I am focused on issues Cuba has with the US. My point is that, without outside political intervention, a country of 11 million can be (empirically proven) self-sustaining with a UBI. Perhaps this is the minimum, perhaps it is the maximum. You are making the political statement. The question is closed, so editing it is moot.

Comment: Is it really ? Your answer has 2 paragraphs. The second, slightly bigger, is focused entirely on this theme, so a little over 50% of your answer is indeed focusing on this matter. Editing your question is a means of both being more helpful to the asker, should the answer be reopen, as well as the other users who might also be interested. You're free to do as you see fit, but I still think you could make your answer much more interesting and productive by detailing how exactly Cuba fits this model and the impacts of the its actual population in this.